# Italicise index entry

Tags: indexing, italic

I am making an index using `makeidx`.

Is the following not okay? This does not work for me.

```
\index{Brazil!\textit{subentry text}}
```

The same without italics (`\index{Brazil!subentry text}`) works fine.

Comment: `\index{Brazil!\textit{subentry text}}` works for me, so I've deleted my first comment. You should say what does not work then!

Comment: Doesn't work in what sense? Do you get an index entry but non-italicised? An error? (Which?!) No entry? Partial entry? Also, since it works in general, we need you to provide a small document which we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the problem (whatever it is). Without understanding the problem, we can't suggest a solution. So 'Is the following not okay?' gets the answer 'No, it's fine.' Now what? Help make it not work for us ;).

Answer (score 9):

The sort order of the subentries will be wrong likely, because `\textit` is included in the sort string. The `@`-notation can be used to specify a sort key without markup commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\null
\index{Brazil!aaa}
\index{Brazil!zzz}
\index{Brazil!\textit{wrong entry}}
\index{Brazil!subentry text@\textit{subentry text}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Commands:

```
pdflatex test
makeindex test
pdflatex test
```

> [image: Result]